# Mule - Calling a flow from another application

Tags: mule

I need to call a flow (server) from another flow (client) in two different applications.
I'd prefer not to create a jar of the server and include it in the client as explained in:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Sharing+Custom+Configuration+Fragments

I try to do that using vm inbound / outbound components but it doesn't work, here you are the configurations file.

For the client flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
    xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
<quartz:connector name="quartzConnector_vm" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz">  
     <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="MuleSchedulerClient1"/>  
     <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.class" value="org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"/>  
     <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="3"/>  
     <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy" value="false"/>  
     <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export" value="false"/>  
     <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.jobStore.class" value="org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore"/>  
   </quartz:connector>
   <flow name="scheduleFlow2" doc:name="scheduleFlow2">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="myQuartzJobName2" repeatInterval="7000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job groupName="DEFAULT" jobGroupName="DEFAULT">
            </quartz:event-generator-job>      
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload="test";]]></expression-component>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="dispatchSingleConfiguration" doc:name="VM">
            <vm:transaction action="NONE"/>
        </vm:outbound-endpoint>
   </flow>
```

The server flow is simply something like this:

```
   <flow name="prepareInputData" doc:name="prepareInputData">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="dispatchSingleConfiguration" doc:name="VM">
            <vm:transaction action="NONE"/>
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
        <set-variable variableName="nomeFileProperties" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
</flow>
```

Is it possible to set properly the path in the vm endpoints to let inbound/outbound VM communication?
I could use an http call, but I think that VM call is a cleaner solution.
Am I wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM is currently (Mule 3.4) only for calls within the same application: to perform remote calls, the easiest is to use HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a bit confused on what "In memory VM" refers to. Two mule applications on the same server does not share the same portion of memory, whilst all the components in a single app do? Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity: VM is only for calls within the same Mule applications. Different applications in the same Mule container (same JVM) or remote applications can not communicate over the VM transport.